# How to move only zip file using java?

Tags: java

i want to move only zip file from one folder to another folder everyday.
Here is found a simple code from Developperzone website but it only copies a known txt file.

I want to use something like *.zip

Thank you

```
import java.io.*;
public class CopyFile
  {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new FileReader("line.txt"));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("linenum.txt"));
    String s, space="  ";
    int num=0;
    while (br.ready())
      {
      s=br.readLine();
      num++;
      bw.write(String.valueOf(num));
      bw.write(space);
      bw.write(s);
      bw.newLine();
      }
    bw.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's not moving/copying a file. That's adding line numbers... which as stands wouldn't work with a zip file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `java.io.File` and its methods to get the list of .zip files and move them (Tutorial - [Moving a File or Directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html)).

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
...
Files.move(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean some like this in linux?

```
mv *.zip dest-dir
```

Why do you want to do this in Java?

I assume you want to move rather than copy?

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to do it in java because i just start to learn java maybe java is not appropriate to do this job, batch file is better? or could u advice? thank you

Comment: @Pacific - There are much better tasks to cut your teeth on than trying to rewrite command shell activities in Java. Try some of the examples on http://www.kodejava.org.