# moving the zip file to other directory

Tags: java

I have a folder in which there is a .dat file and one is .zip file ,I have to move the .zip file to another directory

I have two folders one is

```
1) c:\source folder --> having two files abc.dat and other is abc.zip
2) c:\destination  ---> in which zip shpould be get copied
```

please advise how to achiev this what I have done rite now is ...

```
File directory = new File(sourceFolder);
    File[] listFiles = (mcrpFilePath).listFiles();

 for (File f : listFiles) { 
        if (f.isFile()) {  // ?? here logic to pick up the zip file

        //logic to move the zip file to other directory

            }
        }
```

Comment: You've simply constructed a for-each loop. What have you tried for the logic you want us to construct?

Answer (score 2):

Use [File.renameTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo)

> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.
>   Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.

Here is [Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/)

Or you can use [Files#move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move) (if you are using java 7)

> Move or rename a file to a target file.

here is [Example using move()](http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=334)

Comment: Just as a heads-up, due to API changes, linking to older Java documentation versions such as 1.4.2 is not as good as linking to newer ones such as Java 6 or 7.

Comment: @hexafraction I agree with you.I have updated my answer to link latest one.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as  using the method [renameTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) in File class.

```
public boolean renameTo(File dest);
```

> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.

Get `file` full path and   rename it to the required location.

And make use of `boolean` that return by that method,to know weather it's successfully moved or not.

Answer (score 1):

For detecting your zip-file:

```
if(f.getName.equals("abc.zip"))
```

or for all zip files:

```
if(f.getName.endsWith(".zip"))
```

With a regex:

```
if(f.getName.matches("abc*\\.zip"))
```

For [moving it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo):

```
f.renameTo(new File("C:\dest\abc.zip");
```

## Or, more simply:

```
new File("C:\src\abc.zip").renameTo("C:\dest\abc.zip");
```

catching exceptions as needed.

Comment: I don't think there is a method in the `File` class called `moveTo`. Perhaps you meant `renameTo` like the other answers suggest.

Comment: @hexafraction pls advise the name of zip is the long one and name also contain timesoamp like this abc+timestamp so can I use wild card like abc*.zip so it will be if(f.getName.equals("abc*.zip")) , please advise

Comment: @KonumarMadan Use a regex, and put some research into it on your part. See the edit, and please checkmark the answer that helps most.

Answer (score 1):

Use java.io.File and its methods to get the list of .zip files and move them [(Tutorial - Moving a File or Directory)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html).

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
...
Files.move(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687766/how-to-move-only-zip-file-using-java)